# Inserting XML-tags into database columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have deserialized XML into classes, which works as it should. It returns list- of each XML-tag

This for example, prints all the values of the name tag:

```
   var First = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn).ToList();
                foreach (var o in First)
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + o); 
                }
```

Now I'm wondering if I am able to insert that object into a database table as a column?

Something like this?

```
string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            string sql = null;


            connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=*****;Password=*****";

            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


            connection.Open();



            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Seamen(FirstName) values(@FirstName)", connection);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", First);

            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

I tried this, but got error:

> There is no mapping from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>   [[System.String, mscorlib, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089]] to a built-in type of a known
>   provider.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass `List<string>` as command parameter.
If you want to insert all values from that list, you should iterate thru all items in `First` list (similar to what you did in your first example) and insert values.

c/p of your code:

```
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());


ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


connection.Open();

SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Seamen(FirstName) values(@FirstName)", connection);

foreach (var name in First)
{
    command1.Parameters.Clear();
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", name);

    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

connection.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

I haven't tested it, but that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to insert multiple columns at the same time? Is there a way to loop every column in that loop?